# Number of complete subgraphs in a given undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

What is the best approach to find the number of complete sub-graphs with maximum number of nodes possible, given an undirected graph?
PS: By complete I meant that every node is connected to every other node with an unique edge.

Comment: Each vertex in the graph is a clique of size 1.

Comment: @AmiTavory OP mentioned the word `maximum`, when finding clique becomes a maximizing problem, it becomes NP Complete.

Comment: @PrateekGupta I disagree. Notice the plural *complete sub-graphs*. This is not the clique problem, which maximizes a single *complete sub-graph*. I have to say I think you misread the question.

Comment: @AmiTavory OP has clearly stated that he wants to find number of *complete subgraphs* with ***maximum number of nodes possible***, this makes it a maximizing problem. I don't see what I am missing here, can you please elaborate? I would love to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about [`Clique Problem`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), this is a classical computer science problem, it is NP Complete. Which means that it doesn't have any solution to it, which could run on today's computers in `polynomial time`.

Although, approximation algorithms exist to give a solution, they are weak.

Comment: Is there any way to analyse the number of such sub-graphs without actually finding the number?....Like whether it is greater than some `n` or not....?

Comment: @yobro97 That is the problem with NP-complete problems, there is no solution to them. Although, if you have a *set of vertices*, you can still *verify* whether it is a clique or not in `P time`.

Comment: @yobro97 you cannot efficiently determine if the number if cliques is greater than zero. Any other number in place of zero isn't going to be any easier.

Comment: @n.m. did you mean *greater than one*? Because a subgraph with only 1 vertex is still a clique.

Comment: @PrateekGupta hm no it's my mistake actually.

Comment: I am not down voting because your point is correct, but you should not spread the common misconception that NP-Complete means that no polynomial time solution is possible. Nobody knows that. If you do please come forward and publish. A cool 1 million prize and eternal fame is waiting for you. ;-)